# How to open a terminal window and execute code in the window

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

Put simply, what I want to do is open a terminal window, run some code in it in that terminal window. Ok, there is the simple version. Why I want to do this is that I have created a text based game, and I would like to make the game run on a computer that does not have python installed. The trouble is that I don't want use `tkinter`, or some other GUI module. So how would I open a terminal window and run some code, i.e. `print()`,`input()`,`os.system("cls||clear")`, etc., in it?

-Zeus

Comment: You will need to install Python on the machine to run the code

Comment: Yes, but you can turn python scripts into .app files and .exe files with modules like py2app and cx_frezze.